# Where to start with API's

Tags: api, grails

I am new to API's. I want to create one in grails.
I believe that another application website etc. would just post to a URL in my web-app and it will start a method.
Where is a good place to start my research into this. Any help would be grateful.Thanks.

Comment: Could you try to frame your question more specifically? It's rather broad right now. Perhaps an example of the API request you'd like to work with, and then a first crack at a controller action that processes it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's my first answer but I hope it'll be useful for you :)

Here are some resources you should look into before making your own API:

REST - it's the theory about the whole concept of api you're building. Please find it on Wikipedia. I can't post link because of 2 links limit for new accounts here :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP - this is protocol supported by W3C for exchanging messages. Using standard should help your clients to adopt your api.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oauth - obviously you should authenticate your users somehow. You can do it with Oauth - it's widely open and easy to implement. Again, your clients will have easy time connecting to it.

You will find implementations of all those technologies in Java or as Grails plugin itself.

Comment: +1 Congratulations on your first answer. I thought pointing to REST first was good advice. I've recently been trying to get that clear in my mind and found it improved the manageability of my code.